# How to process multidimensional feature in python?

Tags: data-preprocessing

Hi there so my dataset looks as follow:

| Patient ID | Medicine | Death |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B,C,D,E | 1 |
| 2 | B,D | 0 |
| 3 | A,D,E | 1 |

So my dependent feature is death and my independent feature is medicine. I am trying to predict death based on the medication received by a patient using machine learning.

There are five distinct medicines A, B, C, D, and E. Each patient can be given a combination of these medicines. My question is how do I process the medicine feature vector?

I was thinking to create a dummy binary variable for each medicine to check if it was administered. But that seems quite cumbersome, especially if I have more than 5 medicines say 100 medicines. I appreciate your input on how this feature can be processed, I am sure there is a solution out there to handle this kind of situation which I am not aware of. Thanks.

Comment: The typical approach is what you mentioned: create a binary variable for each medication, indicating whether or not it was administered.

Comment: I see thank you for confirming this. I was not sure about it since I am fairly new to the area.